# How can we use custom data in mapbox clustering?

Tags: swift, mapbox

I have an app in which data is coming from server and with i have to show cluster data on
map box, Please help me if anyone is familiar with that.The format of data coming of server is below.
I have checked Mapbox documentation but in that they using .geojson file that is hard
coaded.

I have coordinates array in response like this

```
  "endPoint" : {
    "coordinates" : [
      -113.16404,
      34.590479999999999
    ],
    "type" : "Point"
  }
```

Comment: Not yet solved?